# {'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

This is the error which is thrown by the `invoice.is_valid()`. I don't know why `invoice` is not valid. If anyone can help me than please.
I am new to Django Rest Framework. I am trying to make a simple invoice generating api. which takes info about seller, buyer, items and generate a invoice. So I write models for each and one model for invoice in which seller, buyer are foriegn key. Item model is related to invoice model through a foreign key.
Any Help is appreciated.

This is my **models.py**

```
    class Seller(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class Buyer(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class Invoice(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
        def total_amount(self):
            total = Decimal('0.00')
            for item in self.items.all():
                total = total + item.total()
            return total
    
        def invoice_number(self):
            if len(str(self.id))==1:
                return 'Invoice00'+self.id
            elif len(str(self.id))==2:
                return 'Invoice0'+self.id
            else:
                return 'Invoice'+self.id
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.seller} {self.buyer} {self.date}'
            
    
    class Item(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        tax = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    
        def total(self):
            total = Decimal(str((self.price-self.tax)*self.quantity))
            return total.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name} {self.quantity}'
```

This is the **serializers.py**

```
    from django.db.models import fields
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from rest_framework.fields import ReadOnlyField
    from invoiceAPI.models import Seller, Buyer, Invoice, Item
    
    class SellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Seller
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class BuyerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Buyer
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Item
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        seller = SellerSerializer(many=False)
        buyer = BuyerSerializer(many=False)
        item = ItemSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Invoice
            depth = 1
            fields = ('seller', 'buyer', 'item', 'date')
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            seller_data = validated_data.pop('seller')
            buyer_data = validated_data.pop('buyer')
            items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
            print(seller_data, buyer_data, items_data)
            seller = Seller.objects.create(**seller_data)
            buyer = Buyer.objects.create(**buyer_data)
            invoice = Invoice.objects.create(seller = seller, buyer = buyer, **validated_data)
            items = []
            for item_data in items_data:
                Item.objects.create(invoice = invoice, **item_data)
            return invoice
```

and this is the **view.py**

```
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def create_invoice(request):
        print('inthe view')
        invoice = InvoiceSerializer(data = request.data)
        if invoice.is_valid():
            invoice.save()    
        return Response({request.data})
```

data for test is

```
    {
        "seller": {
            "name": "Lalit Modi",
            "phone": "9998887776",
            "address": "New delhi"
        },
        "buyer": {
            "name": "Yogi",
            "phone": "9876543210",
            "address": "Aligarh, Uttar pradesh"
        },
        "items": [{
                "name": "Mobile",
                "price": "30000",
                "quantity": "10",
                "tax": "5"
            },
            {
                "name": "Laptop",
                "price": "60000",
                "quantity": "10",
                "tax": "8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Camera",
                "price": "90000",
                "quantity": "5",
                "tax": "18"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**traceback**

```
    InvoiceSerializer(data={'seller': {'name': 'Lalit Modi', 'phone': '9998887776', 'address': 'New delhi'}, 'buyer': {'name': 'Yogi', 'phone': '9876543210', 'address': 'Aligarh, Uttar pradesh'}, 'items': [{'name': 'Mobile', 'price': '30000', 'quantity': '10', 'tax': '5'}, {'name': 'Laptop', 'price': '60000', 'quantity': '10', 'tax': '8'}, {'name': 'Camera', 'price': '90000', 'quantity': '5', 'tax': '18'}]}):
        seller = SellerSerializer():
            id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
            name = CharField(max_length=50)
            phone = CharField(max_length=12)
            address = CharField(max_length=200)
        buyer = BuyerSerializer():
            id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
            name = CharField(max_length=50)
            phone = CharField(max_length=12)
            address = CharField(max_length=200)
        item = ItemSerializer(many=True):
            id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
            name = CharField(max_length=20)
            price = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
            quantity = IntegerField(required=False)
            tax = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
            invoice = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Invoice.objects.all())
        date = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    {'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}
    [19/Aug/2021 18:52:20] "POST /create_invoice HTTP/1.1" 200 5725
```

Comment: Shot in the dark here: have you tried passing the `validated_data` of `buyer` and `seller` to `Invoice.objects.create()` and `Item.objects.create()` instead of the `Buyer` and `Seller` objects?

Comment: Can you share the actual traceback?

Comment: Traceback has been added in the question.

Comment: One issue I see is that you are creating multiple 'Item' objects, but you don't have a ListSerializer. I would suggest first reading the REST documentation on ListSerializers. If you set that up properly, you may have an easier time getting to the root of the issue. I would also suggest looking at the bulk_create() method. This will only touch the database once when creating multiple objects.

Comment: There is an issue with the fact that your InvoiceSerializer has a "item" attribute while you pass "items", even though I don't think that's the reason of the exception.